# Two vertx instances isolated from each other

Tags: java, cluster-computing, microservices, vert.x

we would like to isolate client related (in-browser apps) vertx services from backend (server side) ones. Is there a way how to create two separated (isolated) buses? That all server services would be able to communicate with each other normally, but frontend services must not be on the same bus (got internal events, messages).

I fould a classpath isolation (isolationGroup) feature, but it does not look like what we need.

We need all backend services could communicate with each other. But only one backend module will be accessible from outside and will work as security gate for outer-external communication with frontend modules. So, this gate module would subscribe all messages from internal bus and process it and send them to outer world... and oposite, would subscribe all outer messages and re-send them to internal bus for internal processing.

Any idea? Thanks
W

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with the Hazelcast cluster manager, you can create [separate cluster groups](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6.3/manual/html-single/index.html#creating-cluster-groups).

Check out the documentation for [configuring the cluster manager](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-hazelcast/java/#_configuring_this_cluster_manager).